# Turn data from a datetimepicker (human readable) into Time class (machine readable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, time, datetimepicker

Right now I'm using a datetimepicker to make it easy for users to select an exact date/time and present that in a readable format. However, rails does not like that format and can't Time.parse it.

I've tried out the Chronic gem, and it's close, but it still can't parse something like:

02/27/2013 08:36:57 PM

How can I make user inputted time into an acceptable format for my database? (mongo)

---

I'm using this gem: https://github.com/asgeo1/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails

based on this datetimepicker: https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker

demonstrated here: http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the timeliness gem:
https://github.com/adzap/timeliness

Answer (score 0):

The date picker will always return the value in a standard format, so you can parse it.

```
#02/27/2013 08:36:57 PM
month = input[0..1]
date = input[3..4]
year = input[6..9]
datetime = DateTime.civil(input[6..9], input[0..1], input[3..4],
                          input[11..12], input[14..15], input[17..18])
```